# LWC: conditional display of message

Tags: lightning, javascript, lightning-web-components, template

I have a Lightning component I need to display on a standard lightning page only when the record being displayed meets 2 conditions. Being new to LWC means I'm learning on the go, and am struggling somewhat. This is the code I've achieved so far, but it's the conditions I'm not sure how to implement. How do I get it to display only if the Status = 'Draft' and CertificateType = 'X'?

```
<template>
  <lightning-card title="Alert" icon-name="action:priority">
    <template if:true={cert.data}>
        <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
            Please upload the required documents before setting the Status to Active
            <lightning-output-field value={status__c} name='status' label="Status"></lightning-output-field>
            <lightning-output-field value={certificateType__c} name='certtype' label="Certificate Type" ></lightning-output-field>
        </div>
    </template>       
  </lightning-card>
</template>
```

The JS:

```
import { LightningElement, track, wire, api } from 'lwc';
import sayHello from '@salesforce/apex/CertificationAlert.sayHello';
import { getRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';

const fields = [
'Sync_Detail__c.Status__c',
'Sync_Detail__c.Certificate_Type__c',
'Sync_Detail__c.Name'
];
export default class CertificationAlert extends LightningElement {
//@track greeting = 'World';
//@wire(sayHello) greetings;
@api recordId ;
@wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields }) 
cert;

get name() {
    return this.cert.data.fields.Name.value;
 }
 get status__c() {
   return this.cert.data.fields.Status__c.value;
}
get certificateType__c() {
   return this.contact.data.fields.Certificate_Type__c.value;
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to do anything in your code. You can set this condition in Lightning App Builder. After you click and drag the component on to the page, click on it again to show the menu on the right. You'll see a section called "Set Component Visibility", which allows you to set conditions for its display. From there, you can choose to have it show only when those two conditions are met. You can read more in [Dynamic Lightning Pages](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=lightning_page_components_visibility.htm&type=5).

Comment: Thank you! That makes life a lot easier. Is there a way to check the value of one field to decide whether to display it or not (so I now have the component displaying based on the 2 conditions correctly, but what about displaying different fields (other than the 2 conditional ones) based on what their content is?

Comment: Sorted- I've edited each field to display this way and that works too:  <p if:true={iDDocument}>ID Document</p>. These are checkboxes and the text is displayed only if the field = true!